# Python TypeError when executing unit tests

Tags: python, pybuilder

When running some tests as part of building an application using pybuilder (pyb) getting this exception:

BUILD FAILED - TypeError: () takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given (pybuilder/plugins/python/unittest_plugin.py:177)

What could be possibly wrong ? I checked all the class functions, they have "self" as parameters in them. There are no lambda expressions.

Comment: Kindly add code where you are calling this function

Comment: There are  multiple test modules/files. Not sure which one is causing this. One thing however like to mention. This happens only when using pybuilder 0.12.0 doesn't throw exception when using pybuilder 0.11.17

Comment: It looks like debugging is needed.  Nobody here is likely to be able to do that with the information you have provided.  Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Problem is in that file  pybuilder/plugins/python/unittest_plugin.py. The tests pass when pybuilder 0.11.17 is being used.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved by patching
site-packages/pybuilder/plugins/python/unittest_plugin.py.

The "return runner_generator(stream=output_log_file)" statement was replaced by
"return runner_generator()" in "_create_runner" function.